# GtkBuilder doesnt recognize DTD entity

Tags: gtk

builder.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE interface [
   <!ENTITY bruh "hi">
]>
<interface>
    <object class="GtkWindow">
        <child><object class="GtkButton">
        <property name="label">&bruh;</property>
        </object></child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

app.c

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void handle_gtk_application_activate_app(GtkApplication *app, gpointer userData) {
    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("builder.ui");
    GtkWindow *window = GTK_WINDOW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window"));
    gtk_window_set_application(window, app);

    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(window));
    g_object_unref(builder);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    GtkApplication *app= gtk_application_new("com.fullaccess.MyApp", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(handle_gtk_application_activate_app), NULL);
    int status= g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, (char **)argv);
    g_object_unref(app);
    return status;
}
```

(a.exe:14628): Gtk-ERROR **: 15:57:08.252: failed to add UI from file builder.ui: Error on line 8: Entity name «bruh» is not known

Why is it not known? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried escaping & character?

Comment: Just tried it. It shows a button with the label "&bruh;" but thats not what I want. I want gtk to replace the bruh entity.

Comment: Oh, I see. If I recall correctly, that referencing is not in gtk builder syntax.